# Mac OSX Constantly Forced to Re-authenticate its Wifi Connection

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I'm staying at a hotel where a couple of friend's computers - at least 2 of them - are experiencing problems with connecting to the Internet through our hotel's wifi connection.

The hotel's wifi is configured in a fairly standard method; there's no security on the connection to the wifi itself, but there's a gateway authentication (the name of the filter service seems to be "CloudWiFi" from what I can tell - it's not exactly very specific, I know).

On my Win8 machine, I only have to re-authenticate occasionally (usually after disconnecting from the network for a number of hours, e.g., when I hibernate my laptop when I go to sleep). On my friend's machines (both Mac OSX), however, there are times when they can be forced to reauthenticate as often as every 5-10 minutes while being active on their connection.

Does anyone have any ideas for what exactly could be causing this? We're going to be here for at least a week or two more, and even if it's a shot in the dark, anything would help.

Answer (score 0):

Might be power save mode on the Mac WiFi not being handled correctly by the hotel system - might try tweaking energy saver to save a bit less and plug in if not already plugged in. They default to going into power save mode pretty aggressively (per what my campus WiFi system shows) unless actively transferring data.